# Cant' Display Custom Post Type Title Base on Taxonomy Terms

Tags: wordpress

Trying to list all Custom Post Type titles based on filtered Custom Taxonomy Terms I am getting the list of all post titles instead of getting the list of Queried post. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query(
                  array(
                    'post_type' => 'photos',
                    'technique' => 'zevar',
                    'post_child' => 0,
                    'posts_per_page' => 10
                  )
             );
 ?>
<?php 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 ?>
<?php the_title(); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

As you can see I have a Custom Post Type called "photos" and Custom Taxonomy registered as "technique". Under Taxonomy "technique" I have some terms which one of them is "zevar". Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is 'post_child' => 0 here? I don't see any parameter post_child in wp_query documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your taxonomy query is not correct. check following code.

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query(
                  array(
                    'post_type' => 'photos',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'technique',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'zevar'
                        )
                    ),

                    'posts_per_page' => 10
                  )
             );
 ?>
<?php 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 ?>
<?php the_title(); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Reference on how to use taxonomy parameter https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for you comment but I am getting error message on your code! "SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''posts_per_page'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\CustomPostType_1\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\newPage.php on line 18

Comment: ok.. comma was missing before "posts_per_page", I changed the code.